# How to xcodebuild in php?

Tags: php, xcode, build, xcodebuild

My xcodebuild command working in terminal but it is not working in browser.

My `xcodebuild` build command is here.

`'/usr/bin/xcodebuild -target "AppName" -configuration build PROVISIONING_PROFILE="564-1238-6546-xxxx" -sdk 'sdkPath' CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="certificateName"'.`

I try shell_exec(), exec(), system().

What is wrong going on??

**Please help me..**

Comment: I think before asking "how" you should ask "why."